# Flip-3D on WinXP and taking layered screenshot

Tags: winapi, gdi, aero

I have two questions but somehow related:

1. How to implement flip 3d without Aero APIs on Windows XP?
2. Have you guys seen this awesome app on Mac? http://layersapp.com Is there any possibility to have something similar on Windows? If the #1 question is solved I think we can make something like that

I know how to take a screenshot of a single window, just read the bitmap of a DC. But how to take screenshots of those windows not active on the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how to take screenshots of those windows not active on the top?

You might be able to do this via the [PrintWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869(VS.85).aspx) function. There are some caveats to be aware of. Here is an article detailing its usage: [Capturing Windows Regardless of Their Z-Order](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/gdi/capturingimages/article.php/c11231/).